apply list-returning function to all rows in a pandas DataFrame
I need to apply a function and have the returned list's values inserted into columns in the (new) dataframe. That is, if I have this:
import pandas as pd
def fu(myArg):
    return {"one":myArg,"two":20}
li = [10,20]
df = pd.DataFrame(li,columns=["myArg"])

i would like to apply the fu function to each row of the dataframe so that the output is :
    myArg   one two
0   10      10  20
1   20      20  20

(sorry for the extra spaced there, added for display reasons).
How do I go about doing this, efficiently?

I'm not sure I understand what you're after, but I will note that fu is returning a dict, not a list

Get your function to return a Series, apply, then join:
def fu(myArg):
    return pd.Series({'one': myArg, 'two': 20})

out = df.join(df['myArg'].apply(fu))

If you can't modify the function:
def fu(myArg):
    return {'one': myArg, 'two': 20}

out = df.join(df['myArg'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(fu(x))))

Or convert the Series of dictionaries to DataFrame with json_normalize (warning, json_normalize doesn't maintain the index, you need to set it manually!):
def fu(myArg):
    return {'one': myArg, 'two': 20}

out = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df['myArg'].apply(fu)).set_index(df.index))

Output:
   myArg  one  two
0     10   10   20
1     20   20   20


It seems from your data that column myArg is nothing but a copy of li and column two has the same value in all rows. If that's the case why don't you just do:
out = pd.DataFrame({"one" : li, "two" : 20})

there might be more than that you haven't described in your question.

Yes, this is just a reproducable example. I need to apply a function that returns a dict / list to a dataframe row-wise, and have the results spread out into columns in the dataframe. I do not just want to convert a list to a DataFrame.

Thank you @mozway, the problem was that I needed to return a pandas Series.
Once that is achieved, you can use your join-based approach, or a single call like
dfout = df.apply(lambda x: fu(x['myArg']),result_type="expand",axis=1)

which seems to be a little quicker in my small tests.
Anyway, thank you!
